# Understanding Error C2664: Cannot convert argument 1

Tags: c++, lambda

The following code snippet

```
#include "uWS/uWS.h"

int main()
{
  uWS::Hub h;
  h.onConnection([&h](uWS::WebSocket<uWS::SERVER> *ws, uWS::HttpRequest req) {
    std::cout << "Connected!!!" << std::endl;
  });
  h.run();
}
```

Generates the errors

> `Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error
>   (active)  E0304   no instance of overloaded function
>   "uWS::Hub::onConnection" matches the argument
>   list  pid c:\Users\R\src\main.cpp 6    Error  C2664   'void
>   uWS::Group<false>::onConnection(std::function<void
>   (uWS::WebSocket<false>,uWS::HttpRequest)>)': cannot convert argument 1
>   from 'main::<lambda_1afdd040d2f03ded23f0c636dc85475d>' to
>   'std::function<void
>   (uWS::WebSocket<true>,uWS::HttpRequest)>' pid c:\users\r\src\main.cpp 8`

When built in Visual Studio 2017 IDE using Windows SDK Version 10.0.15063.0, 
where "uWS/uWS.h" contains the [tiny web sockets definitions](https://github.com/uWebSockets/uWebSockets)

What could be the problem?

Comment: hi, have the same question, do you solve this problem now?

Comment: Yep: I changed uWS::WebSocket<uWS::SERVER> *ws to uWS::WebSocket<uWS::SERVER> ws and everything works like a charm. Apparently, the uWS API has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, it looks like the `onConnection` function expects a function which takes a `uws::WebSocket` but your lambda function accepts a `uws::WebSocket*` instead.